# AttributeError: __exit__ with pymc

Tags: python, ipython, anaconda, with-statement, pymc

I am using anaconda python on Ubuntu 12.04 When I try to execute following python code

```
import pymc as pm
import numpy as np

trace = None
with pm.Model() as model:
    alpha = pm.Normal('alpha', mu=0, sd=20)
    beta = pm.Normal('beta', mu=0, sd=20)
    sigma = pm.Uniform('sigma', lower=0, upper=20)

    y_est = alpha + beta * x

    likelihood = pm.Normal('y', mu=y_est, sd=sigma, observed=y)

    start = pm.find_MAP()
    step = pm.NUTS(state=start)
    trace = pm.sample(2000, step, start=start, progressbar=False)

    pm.traceplot(trace);
```

I get following error

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-0d27d14303ac> in <module>()
      3 
      4 trace = None
----> 5 with pm.Model() as model:
      6     alpha = pm.Normal('alpha', mu=0, sd=20)
      7     beta = pm.Normal('beta', mu=0, sd=20)

AttributeError: __exit__
```

How can I fix it ?
What is the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pm.Model()` is not a context manager; it doesn't implement the requisite methods. You probably are running a version of `pymc` where that functionality has not yet been added.

Just assign it to a variable and use directly, *after* creating the elements:

```
alpha = pm.Normal('alpha', mu=0, sd=20)
beta = pm.Normal('beta', mu=0, sd=20)
sigma = pm.Uniform('sigma', lower=0, upper=20)
# etc.
model = pm.Model([alpha, beta, sigma, ...])
```

The [model fitting tutorial](http://pymc-devs.github.io/pymc/modelfitting.html) uses a function to produce the inputs.

Comment: @martijin yes, you are right. I am using older version of pymc instead of pymc 3